# Trying to solve for a '.includes' issue in rails controller active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, include

I am pretty noob ROR coder, but trying to figure out this problem with no luck.  I have an application that is accessing two models:

-Appointments (belongs to a location)
-Locations (has many appointments)

On my Appointment index page I am displaying a map of the locatations with pins using the gmap4rails gem.  That is all working fine, but I cannot figure out how to limit the @appointments to those locations nearby...

```
def index
  @appointments = Appointment.where(active: "TRUE").order("created_at DESC")
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@appointments) do |appointment, marker|
    marker.lat appointment.location.latitude
    marker.lng appointment.location.longitude
  end
end
```

This just gets me all of the appointments that are active.  Its working on my Locations index:

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @locations = Location.near(params[:search], 50)
  else
    @locations = Location.near([session[:latitude], session[:longitude]], 50)
  end
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@locations) do |location, marker|
      marker.lat location.latitude
      marker.lng location.longitude
  end
end
```

I have tried every variation of that query to include Appointment.location.near...

What am I missing here???

Here are the models:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :profile
    belongs_to :length
    belongs_to :location

    has_many :confirmations

    validates_presence_of :title, :comments
end
```

Locations...

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

    geocoded_by :address

    def address
      [address_1, city, state, zip].compact.join(', ')
    end

    after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_1_changed?

    has_many :profile_locations
    has_many :profiles, through: :profile_locations

    has_many :appointments
end
```

Comment: Can you share your Appointments and Locations models, please?

Comment: I think in your appointments controller, you should have the array of nearby locations first (the code may be similar to the @ locations in your locations controller), then from each of those locations get their appointments and set them to @ appointments.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, thats what I was trying to get done, but could not figure it out...  I was trying a few variations on the basic code below that was failing...    

@appointments = Appointment.includes(:location).where(:locaiton.near([session[:latitude], session[:longitude]], 50))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After TONS of different errors, I finally figured it out with this...

```
def index
    location_ids = Location.near([session[:latitude], session[:longitude]], 50, order: '').pluck(:id)
    @appointments = Appointment.includes(:location).where(location_id: location_ids).where(active: "TRUE").order("created_at DESC")

    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@appointments) do |appointment, marker|
      marker.lat appointment.location.latitude
      marker.lng appointment.location.longitude
    end
end
```

Thanks for the guidance, but just needed a little more tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Appointments controller
def index
  nearby_locations = Location.near([session[:latitude], session[:longitude]], 50)
  @appointments = Appointment.where(location: nearby_locations).where(active: true).order(created_at: :desc)
  ...
end
```

Note that you can pass an array of objects/ids (like nearby_locations above) to get back a collection of objects (@appointments above). You can also chain queries with multiple wheres.